# Need to show that T(p + S) = T(p) + T(S).

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

I need to show T(p + S) = T(p) + T(S). Now I know that I can find T(p) by multiplying vector p with matrix A, but what's bothering me is that T(s) has 2 vectors where as T(a) will have 3 vectors. How can I find T(p + S). Can anyone help me.

Comment: Recall your definitions.  For an operator $T$ and a set $X$ you have $T(X) = \{T(x)~:~x\in X\}$.  Next, recall that multiplication by matrices is linear.

Comment: Do i have to multiply S vectors with matrix A to get 2 more matrices?

Comment: In the end, the notation used by your book should have been explained and whatever interpretation you are going with you will have that $T$ will indeed have the property shown... whether you are interpreting this as trying to show $T(p+s) = T(p)+T(s)$ where $s\in \text{span}(S)$ or if you are trying to show $T(p+S)=T(p)+T(S)$ where $a+X = \{a+x~:~x\in X\}$ and $T(S)=\{T(s)~:~s\in S\}$ or whatever else.  Maybe in some notations you have $T(p+S)$ results in a two-element set, maybe it results in an infinite set... but whatever the notation means in your book, you should know and have access.